# How to work with protractor in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I want to include my Protractor testing project on Jenkins.
It's the first time i'm trying to use Jenkins, and I cannot understand what are the steps I need to do to make Protractor work and run in Jenkins.
In addition, how can I make the allure plugin work as well?

By the way, the Protractor might be in the Git in the future.
How all those combinations work?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For configuration of jenkins with protactor please refer to this post https://medium.com/@cnishina/protractor-in-ci-jenkins-6f5fd3fc06ee

In general, executing protactor tests and any other things are ending up in following, if you are able to execute it in command line than you can execute same command under jenkins using "Execute shell" functional of jenkins. A bit more specific: in case of protractor you have this (or something similar) for execution in command line:

`npm install
npm run e2e test-conf.js`

(ofc file names are just samples)